# showDialog(0) in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, fragment

I need use this code in one Fragment:

```
showDialog(0);
```

In one Activity making normally, but in one fragment not i already tryed

```
getActivity().showDialog(0);
```

But also not work;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used these codes to resolve my situation:

```
          // Process to get Current Date
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // Launch Date Picker Dialog
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // Display Selected date in textbox
                                EditText06.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                            }
                        },
                        year, month, day);
                    dpd.show();
```